# Subsetting zoo series by a time that is not in the series

Tags: r, zoo

Is there a good package in R that allows to sub-set (i.e. index into) timeseries by times that are not in the time series? 
E.g. for financial applications, indexing a price series by a time stamp that is not in the database, should return the latest available price before the time stamp.

in code, this is what I would like

```
n =15
full.dates = seq(Sys.Date(), by = 'day', length = n)
series.dates = full.dates[c(1:10, 12, 15)] 
require(zoo)
series=zoo(rep(1,length(series.dates)), series.dates)
series[full.dates[11]]
```

this returns

```
Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
character(0)
```

however, I would like this to return the value of the last existing date before full.dates[11], which is full.dates[10]:

```
series[full.dates[10]]
2014-01-03 
     1
```

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer given by @Henrik, also check na.locf() from zoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`na.locf(x, xout = newdate)` seems not much worse than subscripting but at any rate here we define a subclass of `"zoo"` called `"zoo2"` in which `[` uses `na.locf`.  This is an untested minimal implementation but it could be extended:

```
as.zoo2 <- function(x) UseMethod("as.zoo2")
as.zoo2.zoo <- function(x) structure(x, class = c("zoo2", setdiff(class(x), "zoo2")))
"[.zoo2" <- function(x, i, ...) {
    if (!missing(i) && inherits(i, class(index(x)))) {
        zoo:::`[.zoo`(na.locf(x, xout = i),, ...)
    } else as.zoo2(zoo:::`[.zoo`(x, i, ...))
}
```

This gives:

```
> series2 <- as.zoo2(series)
> series2[full.dates[11]]
2014-01-04 
         1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `index` to extract index of the observations in your `zoo` object. The index can then be used for subsetting the object. Step by step to show the logic (you only need the last step, if I have understood you correctly):

```
# the index of the observations, here dates
index(series)

# are the dates smaller than your reference date?
index(series) < full.dates[11]

# subset observations: dates less than reference date
series[index(series) < full.dates[11]]

# select last observation before reference date:
tail(series[index(series) < full.dates[11]], 1)

# 2014-01-03 
#          1
```

A possible alternative may be to expand your time series and "replac[e] each NA with the most recent non-NA" using `na.locf` and the `xout` argument (see also `?na.locf` and `?approx` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575315/expand-zoo-timeline-in-r/19575922#19575922))

```
# expand time series to the range of dates in 'full.dates'
series2 <- na.locf(series, xout = full.dates)
series2

# select observation at reference date
series2[full.dates[10]]
# 2014-01-03 
#          1
```

If you rather want missing values in your incomplete series to be replaced by "next observation carried backward", you need to `merge` your series with with a 'dummy' zoo object which contains the desired range of consecutive dates.

```
series3 <- merge(series, zoo(, full.dates))
na.locf(series3, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks much, but isn't there a package that already incorporates this very natural functionality?

Comment: If there isn't, can you please suggest the correct syntax to override method [ ] in zoo to include this?   I use zoo objects in the package blotter, and it's destroying my script that I cannot index zoo objects at the times that are not part of the original index. If I could add this functionality into zoo, I think the blotter functions (e.g. updatePortfolio) would start to work magically (or so I hope). Thank you very much again!

Comment: @user3134270, I have updated my answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "cannot index zoo objects at the times that are not part of the original index". Doesn't my first answer suggest that this is possible? Sorry if I have overlooked something obvious. Cheers.

Comment: your solution is not optimal for what I need. I have other packages and functions (i.e. blotter / updatePortfolio ) that use [ ] to subset zoo series.

Comment: given that I don't understand the blotter package too well, the best solution would be to "teach" zoo to return a meaningful result for [ ] method, not write a script to do something different.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific what you mean by '"teach" zoo to return a meaningful result for [ ] method'.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly argue that subset functions should *not* return the prior row if the desired index value does not exist.  Subset functions should return what the user requested; they should not assume the user wanted something different than what they requested.

If this is what *you* want, you can handle it fairly easily with an `if` statement.

```
series.subset <- series[full.dates[11]]
if(NROW(series.subset)==0) {
  # merge series with an empty zoo object
  # that contains the index value you want
  prior <- merge(series, zoo(,full.dates[11]))
  # lag *back* one period so the NA is on the prior value
  prior <- lag(prior, 1)
  # get the index value at the prior value
  prior <- index(prior)[is.na(prior)]
  # subset again
  series.subset <- series[prior]
}
```

Comment: fantastic, bravo, thank you for teaching me elementary R syntax. Can somebody please teach me something a bit more advanced - how to create my own class (or what is it called in R) zoo1, which derives (?) from zoo, and in which the above functionality is part of the [ ] operator. THAT is what I want. For [ ] to return the data. Without additional syntax exposed to the user of that class. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @user3134270: as I said in my answer, this is a really bad idea. You're going to be disappointed because creating a subclass of zoo that subsets how you describe will likely break more than it will fix.  Plus, blotter uses xts, not zoo. If you don't understand how the blotter package works, then you shouldn't expect it to *not* break when you change the behavior of one of its fundamental components. You have two answers to this question. Ask a new question about the actual problem you're trying to solve, not the problem with your attempted solution.